# TMobile Galaxy 3 adjusting between group & single text messaging

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, sms

I want to send the same text to many individual people (only allowed 10 on G3).  I don't want this to go out as a group message where if they reply all the others see the comments.

Someone who has a Galaxy 3 from Verizon tells me he can see other's comments. I cannot choose individual or group on my phone like he can (he sent me a screenshot). I don't have Group Messaging in MMS in settings to disable.

I called TMobile. They said if I send out same text to various people, everyone can see the other's replies, unless they start a new message.

What app can I download or what can I do to send out a text to many recipients, but I only want them to reply to me, not everyone on the recipient list.